# Circuit broken alarm light

Tags: led

I am  using an incandescent light bulb as a heating element in an old freezer to keep my glues and finishes from becoming ruined due to extreme cold ( I live in Alaska where we experience -40 temperatures in the Winter). I want to wire in an alarm light or LED that will turn on if the light bulb burns out. Thanks in advance for your assistance. Also please understand that I am a woodworker and not an electrician other than lighting and electric plug wiring.

Answer (score 2):

Instead providing you with a circuit I would like to propose an alternative solution.

Did you know that if you run a light bulb at a lower voltage it will last a lot longer. What I propose is to connect two identical light bulbs in series.
If you are currently using a 40 W bulb and you connect 2 in series they will burn less power so maybe you will need to increase the wattage of the bulbs, for example 2 x 100 W in series to replace the single 40 W.

This way the light bulbs will run at half their nominal voltage and their lifetime will be much longer than the nominal 1000 hours. The relation voltage vs lifetime is very non-linear so my guess is that at half the voltage the bulbs might last more than 10 times longer !

Comment: Place one bulb in your insulated box and the other where you can see it as a jumbo pilot light.

Answer (score 1):

The [Dwyer series MCS 'miniature current switch'](https://www.dwyer-inst.com.au/Product/ProcessControl/CurrentTransformers-Switches/SeriesMCS) appears to be a good fit for your requirements.

[image]

It is a self-powered device which lights up an LED based on the flow of current. If current is flowing, your light bulbs are OK. If no current is flowing, your light bulbs are dead.

The MCS appears to have two versions, one where you poke the power cable through a hole in the unit, and a second where you terminate the power cables onto screw terminals. From your self-description, both should be within your capability.

If you want an even easier installation, the 'CCS' and 'SCS' models come in a 'split core' version that simply clips on to the power cable, no wiring needed.

The Schneider RM17-J 'current control relay' is a similar product from another manufacturer.

Both of the above are industrial products; I'm not sure where you would buy them as one-off purchases.

Comment: Li-aung Yip, this is exactly what I was looking for. I'll probably put a piece of tape over the green LED so that I only see the light when when the light bulb is out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are not qualified i think you should go for a commercially available product.
If you use a master/slave outlet you will almost get the functiuonality you want.
[http://www.amazon.com/APC-P8GT-Power-Saving-SurgeArrest-Protection/dp/B002K8S2J6](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002K8S2J6)
for instance.
This way you connect a low energy slave lamp that shines as long as your lamp in the fridge works. 
You connect your fridge light to the master outlet and a slave lamp which you can see connected to one of the slave outlets.
Would that work for you?